# angualrjs - form field `username` not working for `$pristine` nor `$error.required`

Tags: angularjs

I am building a custom form fields. i am trying to throw error when user click on the `submit` button on my `username` field.

but some reasons, it's not working. here is my `username` field:

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="formSubmit()" novalidate>

      <input ng-model="fields.name.title" 
      placeholder="Enter your name" name="username" type="text"  required>

      <span ng-show="myform.username.$error.required && !myform.username.$pristine">Invalid name</span>

      <drop-down data="fields.levels" func='levelHandler'></drop-down>

      <drop-down data="fields.stages" func='levelHandler'></drop-down>

      <drop-down data="fields.colors" func='levelHandler'></drop-down>

      <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>

    </form>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OnpxSrEgvn80isXlIRPg?p=preview)

any one help me please?

Comment: This actually works, but I think your logic is off.  The span only works when **both** conditions are met: the field is empty (violates required) and has been modified (violates `$pristine`).  Therefore, it shows when you enter a value and then delete it entirely, and in no other case.  Is that what you were expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `$pristine` property is true unless you enter something in the form (make it dirty).

Try checking for `$submitted` instead.

```
<span ng-show="myform.username.$error.required && myform.$submitted">Invalid name</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change !myform.username.$pristine with myform.$submitted on your ng-show attribute

The complete code should look like

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="formSubmit()" novalidate>

      <input ng-model="fields.name.title" 
      placeholder="Enter your name" name="username" type="text"  required>

      <span ng-show="myform.username.$error.required && myform.$submitted">Invalid name</span>

      <drop-down data="fields.levels" func='levelHandler'></drop-down>

      <drop-down data="fields.stages" func='levelHandler'></drop-down>

      <drop-down data="fields.colors" func='levelHandler'></drop-down>

      <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>

    </form>
```